# Как подключить Susy у меня стоит gulp?

Tags: css, css3, gulp

Как правильно подключить Susy, у меня стоит gulp?
В документации наисано что нужно устанавливать компас:
http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/install/
Но я не хочу его использовать. Есть ли способ правильно подключить susy без компаса используя gulp?

Comment: а где в документации написано, что **нужно** устанавливать компас?

Comment: @Grundy Что вы имеете  в виду? Не могу понять. Говорите прямо что ходите вокруг до около. А если не хотите ответать, ну зачем тогда писали.

Comment: @gilo1212 он имеет в виду, что в доках нет строк, где вас принуждают обязательно устанавливать компас. Т.е. можете ставить без него спокойно

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Это понятно. Дык весь вопрос в том, как тогда её правильно подключить. Чтобы в будущим никаких проблем не вознимало с её работоспособностью.